# ${\rm Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a})={\rm Spec}(A)$ if and only if $\mathfrak{a}$ is generated by nilpotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, nilpotence, zariski-topology

I have been introduced to the Zariski topology and I cant solve this problem:

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity and $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal of $A$, we define ${\rm Spec}(A) $ as the set of prime ideals of $A$, and ${\rm Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a})$ as the set of primes ideals of $A/a$ (which is homeomorphic to the zeros of $\mathfrak{a}$). Knowing this prove:

> ${\rm Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a})={\rm Spec}(A)$ if and only if $a$ is generated by nilpotent elements.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few hints: the (prime) ideals of $A/\mathfrak{a}$ correspond to the (prime) ideals of $A$ containing $\mathfrak{a}$. You can use this idea to get a continuous injective map $\mathrm{Spec}(A/\mathfrak{a}) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

Now, this map is surjective (and in fact a homeomorphism) exactly when all of the prime ideals of $A$ contain $\mathfrak{a}$. This means
$$\mathfrak{a}\subset \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)} \mathfrak{p}.$$
However, there is a characterization of $\mathfrak{N}_A$ (the nilradical of $A$) as
$$
\mathfrak{N}_A = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}(A)}\mathfrak{p}.
$$
Putting these ideas together solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Alekos! now I clearly see the solution